# AngularJS component won't instantiate, "'module' is not a function"

Tags: angularjs

I've been asked to do a project in Angular 1, and I've been having a nightmare of a time just trying to get the page to load the app code from `bundle.js`. I've currently got an error along the lines of

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"_invokeQueue": 
[],"_configBlocks":[],"_runBlocks":[],"name":"approveComponent"} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object
```

but the only approveComponent I've got is essentially a blank placeholder -

> import angular from 'angular';
>
> const approve = angular.module('approveComponent', []);
>
> export default approve;

What can I do to get this actually running?

I'm using Webpack 4 to bundle everything. (NO errors from webpack.)

Comment: did the answer help?

Comment: It didn't, but for various other reasons the structure of the project is now completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error earlier.You need to pass module name not module in the dependency

```
ngModule = angular.module('webpack', [
    require('./webpack/photocrop/client')//this is a object
])
```

You can simply require the file and just inject by name Like this

```
var firstModule = require('./webpack/myapp/client')

ngModule = angular.module('webpack', [
        'firstModule'//this is should work
])
firstModule(ngModule)
```

**[SAMPLE GITHUB REPO](https://github.com/blinfo/webpack-angular-seed/blob/master/app/second-module/index.js)**